# boost.mpi.world Communicator did not match C++ signature: boost::mpi::communicator

Tags: python, c++, boost, mpi, boost-python

I am doing my best to link a C++ module to a python binding. I am struggling to realize boost mpi communication. I am sending the `boost.mpi.world` object to C++, and it is expecting a `boost::mpi::communicator` object. When I call my C++ funciton from python, it raises a mismatched signature error.

```
myModule.myfunc(Communicator, NoneType, NoneType, _ExcInfo) did not match C++ signature:
myfunc(boost::mpi::communicator {lvalue}, char*, char*, boost::python::api::object)
```

I don't understand - it really looks like these are the same object and should therefore have the same C++ signature.

Am I using boost mpi correctly? What could be causing this issue?

**Attempt at a Repeatable Example**

To recreate this, I made a setup.py file and a wrapper.cpp file containing my function:

wrapper.cpp:

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numeric.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>

#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#endif

namespace bp = boost::python;
namespace bpn = boost::python::numeric;

int run_mod_mpi(boost::mpi::communicator &_mpi)

{
  return 111;
}

#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(myMod)
{
  using namespace bpn;

  def("run_my_mpi_mod", run_mod_mpi, "run my module with mpi");
}
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
import os

include_dirs = ['/nopt/nrel/apps/boost/1.55.0-openmpi-gcc_140415/include']
library_dirs = ['/nopt/nrel/apps/boost/1.55.0-openmpi-gcc_140415/lib']

EXTRA_LIBS = ['gfortran']

sources = ['wrapper.cpp']

external_libs = [
    'boost_regex', 'boost_filesystem', 'boost_serialization', 'boost_system',
    'boost_signals', 'boost_python']#, 'lapack', 'blas']

external_libs.append('boost_mpi')
os.environ['CC'] = 'mpicxx'


libraries = external_libs + EXTRA_LIBS

myMod = Extension(name='myMod',
                     sources=sources,
                     include_dirs=include_dirs,
                     library_dirs=library_dirs,
                     libraries=libraries,
                     language='c++')

setup(name='myMod',
      description='a module I made',
      py_modules=['dakota', 'test_dakota'],
      ext_modules=[myMod],
      zip_safe=False,
      )
```

Problem:

```
$ python setup.py build
$ cd build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
$ ipython

In [1]: import myMod
In [2]: from boost.mpi import world
In [3]: myMod.run_my_mpi_mod(world)
Out[3]: 111
```

So, I misdiagnosed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You were expected to give `**char*, char***` as the second argument but you put two NoneType objects there instead.